# Web UI(http://localhost:8088) is not showing Spark Applications

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have pseudo distributed hadoop 2.2.0 Environment setup in my laptop.I can run mapreduce applications(including Pig and Hive jobs) and the status of the applications can be seen from the Web UI `http://localhost:8088`

I have downloaded the Spark library and just used the file system-HDFS for the spark applications.when I launch a spark application,it is getting launched and the execution also gets completed successfully as expected.

But the Web UI `http://localhost:8088` is not listing the Spark application completed/launched.

Please suggest if there is any other additional configuration is required for seeing Spark applications in the Web UI.

(Note: `http://localhost:50070`this Web UI shows the files correctly,when tried writing files to HDFS via Spark applications)

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the submit script and the spark configuration?

Comment: Hi,I have executed the following script(came up as an example script with Spark)... >>run-example SparkPi 2 spark://localhost.I didn't configure anything specifically for Spark.Just added the Spark's bin location to the PATH variable.Remaining configuration properties are from Hadoop(I mean HDFS and map reduce properties).please suggest if there is any xml file configuration is required for spark application to get logged(I'm new to Spark!!).

Answer (score 5):

You might have figured it out but for others who are starting with Spark.You can see all the spark jobs on

> http://localhost:4040

after your spark context is initiated(port can be different eg 4041). Based on Standalone installation you can see the master and slave status on

> http://localhost:8080

(for slave port is usually 8081 onward). you need to Spark-submit jobs to yarn-cluster or client to see the same on hadoop webservices.

Comment: this seems to be true for shell based drivers (pyspark, spark-shell etc) but not for launched applications.